# if statement inside of event listener not working for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, listener, keyup

Making this super simple game.  You hold the space bar and the timer starts, when you release the space bar it stops and if you have beaten your high score then it will update high score otherwise it resets the timer to 0 and keeps the high score the same.  I can't get the high score to stay the same if the timer is under the high number.  It changes every time

```
`use strict`;

let timer = document.getElementById(`number`);
let highScore = document.getElementById(`highNumber`);
let resetBtn = document.getElementById(`resetBtn`);

let timerNumber = 0;

startTimer();
function init() {}

function startTimer() {
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
        timer.textContent = timerNumber++;
    }
});
}

document.addEventListener(`keyup`, (event) => {
if (timer.textContent > highScore.textContent) {
    highScore.textContent = timerNumber;
    timer.textContent = 0;
    timer.textContent = 0;
    timerNumber = 0;
}
if (timer.textContent < highScore.textContent) {
    timer.textContent = 0;
    timer.textContent = 0;
    timerNumber = 0;
}
});

function reset() {
resetBtn.addEventListener(`click`, function () {
    highScore.innerHTML = 0;
});
}
reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't add `keyup` or `keydown` event to `document` give it to the `<html>` tag :

```
document.querySelector("html").addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>{
  //something
});
```